# jQuery json value is not being appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my code:

```
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("done");
            $.each(jsonData, function(key, value) {
                if (value !== "") { console.log("working on " + "#"+key+".div")
                    $("#"+key+".div").append("<pre>"+value+"</pre>");
                }
            });
        }
```

As you see, this is a snippet of the success callback function.

Everything works fine up to the point where value should be appended to the selector I provide. But for some reason, nothing is added.

```
console.log("working on " + "#"+key+".div")
```

Is printed, so I know the if statement is not the issue.

I believe the error lays with this line:

```
$("#"+key+".div").append("<pre>"+value+"</pre>");
```

But I can't tell what exactly I am missing.

Exemplary HTML :

```
<div id="prx1.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="prx2.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="sh1.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="sh2.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="sh3.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="sh4.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="sh5.sjc.div"></div>
<div id="sh6.sjc.div"></div>
```

Comment: what is `.div`, can you share the html for the target element

Comment: What is the value of `$("#"+key+".div")`, can you provide the element it should match?

Comment: Can we see the HTML ? This selector is strange : why not just '#'+key ?

Comment: If you are identifying the selected element to append to with the `id`, you shouldn't need the `.div` (which says 'class="div"').

Comment: @DevlshOne - I see. Do you happen to know of a way to use jQuery to escape those dot chars with a backslash?

Comment: @elad.chen Just get rid of the .div and use the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the dot in a id (or class) attribute it's not a good practice.

If you want to refer a id like this:

```
<div id="sh6.sjc.div"></div>
```

you have to escape the dot in this way

```
$("#sh6\\.sjc\\.div")
```

The dot is reserved in the [selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). In the linked reference is written:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Without escaping the dot you'll select an object with id "sh6" which has two classes "sjc" and "div", something like

```
<div id="sh6" class="sjc div"></div>
```

**Shortcut**

An interesting shortcut for escaping the jquery selector is in this [article](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) of the jQuery blog.

**Checking the selectors**

When you are dealing with this issues, check if the selector match some elements, using something like

```
console.log("Matching the id sh6.sjc.div, occurrences:"+$("#sh6\.sjc\.div").length);
```

It's easier to verify the correctness of the selector you're using

Comment: I suspected this was the issue. Is there a search and replace function I can use ? (look for "." and replace with "\.")

Comment: @elad.chen In Eclipse as well as in any others IDE there is a search and replace function. But are you searching for a replace function in javascript? I don't think it's necessary: if your ID is formatted like this, you have just to edit the js function.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/ Add this to your answer, and I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to add content to a div with the id `"#"+key`
Use

```
$("div#"+key).append("<pre>"+value+"</pre>");
```

or

```
$("#"+key).append("<pre>"+value+"</pre>"); //You don't need to add a tag selector, since you already have the id of the element
```

Comment: See my HTML, I believe the selector I'm using is fine.

Comment: Can you change the way the id's are generated? Because your the selector `#prx1.sjc.div` will try to find an element with id 'prx1' with css class 'sjc' and 'div' hence failing to find an element.

Comment: Too much is based on those. Is this a matter of jQuery treating ".div" as a class ? (although the evaluated string is #prx1.sjc.div)

Comment: Yes that is how jQuery treats the selector as is, however @MPavesi already provided an answer to escape the '.' Try that